# open page in new tab using angular js ui-router on right click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

$stateProvider

```
    // Home route
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        views: {
            '': { 
                    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html' ,
                    controller : 'WelcomeCtrl'
                },
            'columnOne@dashboard': { 
                templateUrl: 'views/addCompany.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            }
        }
    });
```

How to load addCompany tab on right click using angularjs ui router?

Comment: You can define this in your HTML element. You can provide a target attribute in the anchor element to keep it simple.
<a target="_blank"......>

Comment: when I reload the page it always load dashboard template but I want to load the add company template

Comment: Angular is a single page web application. When you reload, it always depends on the URL that was mentioned and not based on the page you are currently in.

Comment: @CrazyMac yeah it will be good for me to if you provide any idea how to load child URL on reload page and also when I go to new tab using context menu item "open in new tab". Thanks

Comment: If you want to land in a particular page on right click of a link, provide the mapping accordingly. For ex: if you want to land in addCompany.html, ensure you have a mapping for it and the right click URL should match that mapping.

If your mapping for addCompany.html is /addCompany then your URL should be something like  http://...../addCompany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code.

```
      <a ng-href="/columnOne@dashboard" target="_blank">New Tab</a>
```

Comment: it's fine but when i reload the page it execute the main controller where i m using $state.go either dashboard state or login, so how can i be in the same template after reload

Comment: $state.reload();. I can't get your question.